# Identity userManager.FindByNameAsync() returns null value

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-identity

I'm upgrading an old project in **ASP .Net 5** to **ASP .Net 7**
and when i try to use `userManager.FindByNameAsync()` it returns the following exception in the API Response :

```
System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlNullValueException: Data is Null. 
This method or property cannot be called on Null values.
```

knowing that **it works** with no problems **in ASP .Net 5**.
[Here is the full exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KXzKM.png):

I tried to troubleshoot the problem using the Visual Studio debugger and set a breakpoint to track the value which should be stored in a variable called user containing the returned value from the database using `userManager.FindByNameAsync()`.

When the cursor reaches the toggle point the error is thrown and the rest of the program stops debugging
knowing that the value i'm passing to the function is correct!
The user I'm looking for is created using `userManager.CreateAsync()`
This is the model that i'm trying to get:

```
namespace API.Models
{
    public class User : IdentityUser<int>
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        //********** Visa Info**********
        public string ClientName { get; set; }
        public string BankName { get; set; }
        public int AccountNumber { get; set; }
        public string Section { get; set; }
        public int CardNumber { get; set; }
        public string CardName { get; set; }
        public int WalletNumber { get; set; }
        public string lastName { get; set; }
        public string address { get; set; }
        public string ImageID { get; set; } 
        public int TotalProfits { get; set; } = 0;
        public int WithdrawnProfits { get; set; } = 0;

        public virtual ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Order> Orders { get; set; }
        public ICollection<UserRole> UserRoles { get; set; }
        public ICollection<WithdrawRequest> WithdrawRequests { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<UserBill> UserBills { get; set; }
    }
}
```

this is the function:

```
private async Task CreateAdmin()
        {
            var admin = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync("Admin");

            if (admin == null)
            {
                var newUser = new User
                {
                    Email = "admin@admin.com",
                    UserName = "Admin",
                    PhoneNumber = "0796544854",
                    EmailConfirmed = true
                };

                var createAdmin = await _userManager.CreateAsync(newUser, "1234");

                if (createAdmin.Succeeded)
                {
                    if (await _roleManager.RoleExistsAsync("Admin"))
                        await _userManager.AddToRoleAsync(newUser, "Admin");
                }

                var newShippCompany = new ShippingCompany
                {
                    Id = 1,
                    companyName = "Not Attached",
                    companyPhone = null
                };

                await _souqlyRepo.Add(newShippCompany);
                await _souqlyRepo.SaveAll();
            }
        }
```

And this is the error from the API Response: -

```
{System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlNullValueException: Data is Null. This method or property cannot be called on Null values.
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlBuffer.ThrowIfNull()
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlBuffer.get_String()
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.GetString(Int32 i)
   at lambda_method42(Closure, QueryContext, DbDataReader, ResultContext, SingleQueryResultCoordinator)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SingleQueryingEnumerable`1.AsyncEnumerator.MoveNextAsync()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.ShapedQueryCompilingExpressionVisitor.SingleOrDefaultAsync[TSource](IAsyncEnumerable`1 asyncEnumerable, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.ShapedQueryCompilingExpressionVisitor.SingleOrDefaultAsync[TSource](IAsyncEnumerable`1 asyncEnumerable, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager`1.FindByNameAsync(String userName)
   at API.Controllers.AuthController.CreateAdmin() in /Users/ahmedgamal/projects/API/Controllers/AuthController.cs:line 84
   at API.Controllers.AuthController.Login(UserForLogin userForLogin) in /Users/ahmedgamal/projects/API/Controllers/AuthController.cs:line 149
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor.TaskOfIActionResultExecutor.Execute(ActionContext actionContext, IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[] arguments)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionMethodAsync>g__Awaited|12_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, ValueTask`1 actionResultValueTask)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeNextActionFilterAsync>g__Awaited|10_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContextSealed context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeInnerFilterAsync>g__Awaited|13_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeNextResourceFilter>g__Awaited|25_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContextSealed context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeFilterPipelineAsync>g__Awaited|20_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI.SwaggerUIMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.SwaggerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext, ISwaggerProvider swaggerProvider)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddlewareImpl.Invoke(HttpContext context)

HEADERS
=======
Accept: */*
Connection: keep-alive
Host: localhost:5077
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/108.0.0.0 Safari/537.36
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
Content-Type: application/json-patch+json
Cookie: _xsrf=2|7ddc8933|478e981c349410ca2e05fa7b50dcaeee|1671139281; username-localhost-8888="2|1:0|10:1671456298|23:username-localhost-8888|44:NjA1OTkxOTgzZjFhNDE1MWFhOTIxNWQ3ZDczZjU1MjY=|5ae71afcdb82e897faa88c8158ab4ccb4edfbe7e4478f2e6dc88926938171b11"; .AspNetCore.Antiforgery._EomAn3AoJg=CfDJ8Oe9S8Poye1KncOFEtdCmBpov-Z4Szk20KKrAQTFIPoPKPabF-KF8zohP-BZVw8pL_FKLxPvrlxXrZt5K5SBF3YB9-5Lul_q0outcr2kZgyc4glteG-JGf8j0_pq2-a0_DN9WupHrzZo3igvLzqBsoQ; .AspNetCore.Session=CfDJ8Oe9S8Poye1KncOFEtdCmBr0c19qm2tGMZe7b6rkQbgsvt77HALStTx0XC86brZHEp8kf6YdM46RUT1wt0K6Wfa7mMXMXHE58ap382sIuQOtujORzTAnlBVLypOYMuJTwj%2BLmJ4lrUHWyY98ViOI9UdtLv1N6Nifn4%2BfUZE2I9QM
Origin: http://localhost:5077
Referer: http://localhost:5077/swagger/index.html
Content-Length: 116
sec-ch-ua: "Not?A_Brand";v="8", "Chromium";v="108", "Google Chrome";v="108"
sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
sec-ch-ua-platform: "macOS"
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-origin
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
}
```

Comment: It kinda sounds more like a data problem, i.e. the user manager finds a table row for "Admin", but one of the columns contains an unexpected `NULL` value which then can't be converted to a `string` in order to set on of the `string` properties of the `User` object. Have you looked at the row in the DB?

Comment: @GoodNightNerdPride
It is only one row and to make sure i filled all the properties with values but still not working
In fact it was working perfectly in asp .net 5 that is the ambiguous thing

Comment: This seems related: https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/22812 Maybe try disabling nullable reference types.

Comment: @GoodNightNerdPride
I've disabled it from the database design for AspNetUsers Table for UserName property and still not working

Comment: @GoodNightNerdPride
The error disappears when I set values for all properties in the row that i want to retrieve
and that wasn't the case in asp .net 5
Is that from the updates in asp .net 7 ?
And if Yes then why ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

find this line in your csproj file and disable it

```
<Nullable>enable</Nullable>
```

it would be there by default in .net 6/7 but don't exist by default in .net 5,That's why you got the error in .net 7 but didn't get the error in .net 5

You could check the related [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/nullable-reference-types) for more details

Comment: Yes That solved the whole problem , Thanks a lot I got stuck with it all the night

Answer (score 0):

try with await keyword

```
await userManager.FindByNameAsync();
```

Comment: Still not solving the problem